# $X,Y,Z$ are random variables $P(X\mid Y,Z)=P(X\mid Y)$ when $X$ and $Z$ are independent - true or false

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

if $X,Y,Z$ are random variables does $P(X\mid Y,Z)=P(X\mid Y)$ when $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

I thought it's true because $X$ is independent in $Z$, and therefore providing data about $Z$ does not affect the distribution of $X$, but I couldn't prove it.
(I think I saw that in this case $X-Y-Z$ is a Markov chain so it should be true)

One more question:
Assuming that {$Y = Y_1 \: \text{ if }\:  Z=0; Y_2 \:\text{ if }\: Z=1$} where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are also random variables, can I write that:
$P(X \mid  Y, Z=0)= P(X\mid Y_1)$ and  $P(X\mid  Y, Z=1)= P(X \mid Y_2)$? it seems to me that if the statement above is true then I can't write it.

Sorry if my question is not so smart, sometimes these notations in probability makes me frustrated.

Comment: Hint: Do you know any examples of random variables which are pairwise independent but not mutually independent?

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Yes. I think I get what you're saying. if we take the example in which all random variables are pairwise independent but not mutually independent, then it satisfies my condition and if my statement was  true then $P(X∣Y,Z)=P(X∣Y)=P(X)$ which is not true. So it's should not always form a Markov chain. So about the last question it's true to write it as  shown there? $P(X∣Y,Z=0)=P(X∣Y1)$ and $P(X∣Y,Z=1)=P(X∣Y2)$.

Comment: The expressions $\mathbb P(X\mid Y,Z)$ and $\mathbb P(X\mid Y)$ are meaningless. Probabilities are defined on events - measurable subsets of the sample space. It makes no sense to speak of the probability of a random variable, which is a measurable *function* defined on the sample space.  Instead you should write something like 
$$
F_{X\mid Y,Z} = F_{X\mid Y},
$$
where $F_\cdot$ denotes the distribution function of a random variable.